# cart functionality how to fetch products from 2 different tables in php

Tags: javascript, php, sql

i have created a cart functionality in php, which gets products from 1 table and displays it in the cart page using session. 
the code which fetches the products is below:

```html
<?php

// load database connection script

include("database_connection.php");

/*
 * Tutorial: PHP MySQL Shopping cart
 *
 * Page: Application library
 * */

class ShopingCart
{



    protected $db;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = DB();
    }

    /**
     * get products list
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getProducts()
    {
        $query = "SELECT *  FROM `entertainment`";
        if (!$result = mysqli_query($this->db, $query)) {
            exit(mysqli_error($this->db));
        }
        $data = [];
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
        }

        return $data;
    }

    /**
        * get given product details
        *
        * @param [integer] $id
        * @return array
        */
       public function getProductDetails($id)
       {
           $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db, $id);
           $query = "SELECT *  FROM `entertainment` WHERE `id` = '$id'";
           if (!$result = mysqli_query($this->db, $query)) {
               exit(mysqli_error($this->db));
           }
           $data = [];
           if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
               while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                   $data['id'] = $row['id'];
                   $data['title'] = $row['title'];
                   $data['price'] = $row['vendor_price'];
                   $data['quantity'] = 1;
               }
           }

           return $data;
       }

       /**
        * Add new product into the cart
        *
        * @param [integer] $id
        * @return void
        */
       public function addToCart($id)
       {

         $product = $this->getProductDetails($id);

         $isFound = false;
         $i = 0;

         if (!isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart']) || count($_SESSION['shopping_cart']) < 1)
         {
             $_SESSION['shopping_cart'] = array(0 => $product);
         } else {

             foreach ($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $item) {
                 $i++;
                 foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
                     if ($key == "id" && $value == $id) {
                         array_splice($_SESSION['shopping_cart'], $i - 1, 1, array([
                             'id' => $item['id'],
                             'title' => $item['title'],
                             'price' => $item['vendor_price'],
                             'quantity' => $item['quantity'] + 1,
                         ]));
                         $isFound = true;
                     }
                 }

             }
             if ($isFound == false) {
                 array_push($_SESSION['shopping_cart'], $product);
             }
         }





       }

       /**
        * remove existing product from the cart
        *
        * @param [integer] $id
        * @return void
        */
       public function removeProductFromCart($id)
       {
           unset($_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$id - 1]);
       }


}

?>
```

the cart page code is below:

```html
<?php

// Start Session
session_start();

// Application library ( with ShopingCart class )
require __DIR__ . '/library.php';

$app = new ShopingCart();

if(isset($_POST['add_to_cart']))
{
    $app->addToCart($_POST['id']);
}

if (isset($_GET['id_to_remove']) && isset($_GET['id_to_remove']) != '') {
    $app->removeProductFromCart($_GET['id_to_remove']);
}

?>



<h5 style="font-size:20px;" class="card-header">My Shopping Cart</h5>
            <div class="card-body">

                <?php
                    if(isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart']) && count($_SESSION['shopping_cart']) > 0)
                    {
                        $entertainment = $_SESSION['shopping_cart'];

                        echo '
                                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Title</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Price</th>
                                    <th scope="col" width="100">Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>';

                        $item_number = 1;
                        $total = 0;
                        foreach ($entertainment as $product) {
                        echo '
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">'. $item_number .'</th>
                                    <td>' . $product['title'] . '</td>
                                    <td>'.$product['quantity'].'</td>
                                    <td>₹ '. $product['price']. '</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="cart.php?id_to_remove=' . $item_number . '" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">X</a>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                           ';
                           $total += ((int)$product['price'] * $product['quantity']);
                            $item_number++;
                        }

                        echo '
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="4" align="right">
                                        Total:
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        ₹ '. $total .'
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>';

                    }
                    else {
                        echo '<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
                              Shopping cart is empty, add items into shopping cart.
                            </div>';
                    }
                ?>

            </div>

            <?php
            if(isset($product['title'])){
              echo
             '.<div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary float-right">Proceed To Checkout</button>
            </div>.';
}?>
        </div>
```

below are my table structure

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
now i have some products in another table, with different column names. i want to use this same code to fetch them also. but as i am new to php, i am not able to find a way. can anyone help

Comment: Please share both table structures

Comment: Kindly share the precise content. Probably you have added your whole project here :(

Comment: @ZainFarooq actually this is my table structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can select data from the second table and cast the column name as first table column names. Then you can merge both arrays into single. 
This is possible when you have the number of fields are same , otherwise you need to put dummy values to that columns

Eg  : select product as title, amount as price, number as quantity from product2 table in mysql

Comment: Give me  both table structure

Comment: SELECT column_name AS alias_name
FROM table_name;